# Whay is the most elegant way to turn a hash inside out?

Tags: perl, hash

What is the most elegant way to turn a hash inside out?

By that I mean replace keys with values and vice versa (assuming that all the values are 100% unique).

E.g.

Start with

```
my %start = (1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c");

# ...

# PROFIT: 
my %finish = ("c" => 3, "b" => 2, "a" => 1);
```

I know I can do it the brute force way:

```
foreach my $key (keys %start) {
    my $value = $start{$key};
    $finish{ $value } = $key;
}
```

But this can't be the most Perly-elegant way of doing so!

Comment: Your brute force method doesn't work correctly.  You'd need to loop over `keys %start`.

Comment: What does "100% unique" mean? Do you work in advertising? Can something be "95% unique"? Do you tell your wife she's your "95% unique love"?

Comment: @cjm - right you are. I edited to fix the code, and added some cleanup by way of declaring variables to be lexical in smallest scope (in other words, added `my` everywhere). Ike - feel free to revert the edits if you disagree.

Comment: @KerrekSB - I work as software developer. It means there are no duplicates, meaning you don't have to worry about multiple keys being mapped from the same value (in which case you need to either lose some keys, or add a set of keys as a list). I'm sorry if my English isn't perfect.

Comment: @Ike I think Kerrek is pointing out that they are either unique or not, there's no in between.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`reverse` is probably among the most idiomatic ways:

```
my %finish = reverse %start;
```

This works, because reverse takes the `%start` hash as a list of the form (key1 value1 key2 value2... keyN valueN); then reverse reverses the list (valueN keyN ... value1 key1). Assigning that list to a hash variable then turns it into a hash with odd elements becoming keys and even elements becoming values

Or you can use `map` (less elegant but still idiomatic):

```
my %finish = map { ( $start{$_} => $_ ) } keys %start;
```

Comment: `@finish{value %start} = keys %start` preserves existing pairs.

Comment: `reverse %start` is clever, but maybe a bit too clever.

Comment: @tchrist - could you please clarify? What does "preserves existing pairs" mean?

Comment: @tchrist, also, you left off the 's' in `values`.  (See my answer, posted just 1 second before your comment.)

Comment: @Ike My version adds stuff to an existing hash. It preserves extant key/value pairs for those pairs whose keys are not reassigned.  The `reverse` version only works if you want a brand new hash.

Comment: @cjm How can `reverse` be too clever? If they don’t understand hashes, they should learn.  A hash in list context is its k/v pairs, which reversed necessarily become v/k pairs. Assigning lists to hashes pulls in those v/k pairs. **THAT** solution took me less than a minute to explain before my class caught on.  The slice took a bloody half-hour.

Comment: @tchrist - was my attempt to explain how it works any good in your professional opinion? (no need to be gentle :)

Comment: The reverse is fine.  I just have to figure out a better way to explain the slice solution. I think you have to build up to it with `@ary[3,1,4] = ("fee", "foo", "furple")` or something.  But that needs to show the `($a[3], $a[1], $a[4]) = ...` bit first.  Dunno. Hash slices with the `@name{...}` break all beginners’ brains, which means they have somehow gotten the wrong idea about everything.  They desperately want that to be a `%` there.

Comment: @tchrist - the most intuitive explanation I've seen was "the sygil represents the amount of data from the data structure that you are retrieving ($ of 1 element, @ for a list of elements, % for entire hash) whereas the brace style represent what your data structure is (square for array, curly for hash).

Comment: @DVK, It's often not the case. Counter example: `@a = %h;`. `@a` returns an array instead of a list, and `%h` returns a list instead of a hash.

Comment: @ikegami - while a valid example as far as general Perl syntax, the explanation was intended to help with $SYGIL$BRACKET$EXPRESSION$CLOSEBRACKET syntax only (at least that's how I understood tchrist's dilemma scope).

Comment: If you mean `$SYGIL$BRACKET$EXPRESSION$CLOSEBRACKET`, that doesn't change anything: `@{ $aref } = %{ $href }`, and it doesn't help tchrist who said he has problem teaching people @foo{'x','y'} accesses a hash.

Comment: If you mean `$SYGIL$IDENTIFIER$BRACKET$EXPRESSION$CLOSEBRACKET`, what you said makes no sense since `%` cannot be used there, and it doesn't help tchrist who said he has problem teaching people `@foo{'x','y'}` accesses a hash.

Comment: @ikegami - How does it not? "whereas the brace style represent what your data structure is (square for array, curly for hash)" => @foo{'x','y'} is accessing a hash because of "{}".

Comment: @DVK, Exactly, now read what you said. "the sygil represents the amount of data from the data structure that you are retrieving" is not only is what you said wrong, it doesn't help tchrist. Only the second half of what you have is true and useful.

Comment: @ikegami - I said 2 halves of the sentence. Why are you saying the 1st half is wrong when the 2d one is what applies to tchrist's dilemma? And how is first one is wrong? @x{'x','y'} retrieves a list of values, as can be deduced from the sygil according to my rule.

Comment: I'm saying the first half is wrong because it is, as I showed above. That the second half applies doesn't make the first half any less wrong

Answer (score 10):

```
my %start = (1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c");

my %finish;
@finish{values %start} = keys %start;
```

Comment: Last week it took me like half a [CENSORED] hour to explain that solution to a Beginning Perl class.  I’ve decided to remove it from the materials.  They simply *cannot* understand hash slices.  They get in stuck in their heads that `@` means array; they don’t understand that it takes the `{` to mean a hash and that the `@` is immaterial.

Comment: Virtual +1 (Can't upvote yet) for a clever solution. I'm not quite a complete beginner so didn't have same problem as students in the above comment :)

Comment: @ike - you should have enough rep to up-vote non-virtually now. And +1 from me for a great idiomatic expression